# Handling a event return on AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I am currently using the lambda to send a API details to get a access token. I then want to save that access token to use later on. It seems it doesn't save the access key. Any tips?
Lambda:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
var data = qs.stringify({
  'client_id': 'theID',
  'client_secret': 'theSecret',
  'scope': 'ski',
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials' 
});
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'myendpoint',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data : data,
};    

        const postData = await axios.post('myendpoint',data, config)
        console.log(postData);
        
        
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(postData.response.data.access_token),
    };
    var mykey = data.access_token;
    return response;
};
```

Here is my Error Report:

```
 Response
    {
      "errorType": "TypeError",
      "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined",
      "trace": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:26:48)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
      ]
    }
```

Here is my logs:

```
    Function Logs
    gOutput],
        agent: Agent {
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          defaultPort: 443,
          protocol: 'https:',
          options: [Object],
          requests: {},
          sockets: [Object],
          freeSockets: {},
          keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
          keepAlive: false,
          maxSockets: Infinity,
          maxFreeSockets: 256,
          scheduling: 'fifo',
          maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
          totalSocketCount: 1,
          maxCachedSessions: 100,
          _sessionCache: [Object],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        path: 'API/connect/token',
        _ended: true,
        res: IncomingMessage {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 3,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          socket: [TLSSocket],
          httpVersionMajor: 1,
          httpVersionMinor: 1,
          httpVersion: '1.1',
          complete: true,
          headers: [Object],
          rawHeaders: [Array],
          trailers: {},
          rawTrailers: [],
          aborted: false,
          upgrade: false,
          url: '',
          method: null,
          statusCode: 200,
          statusMessage: 'OK',
          client: [TLSSocket],
          _consuming: false,
          _dumped: false,
          req: [Circular *1],
          responseUrl: 'myendpoint',
          redirects: [],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
        },
        aborted: false,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        reusedSocket: false,
        host: 'myhost',
        protocol: 'https:',
        _redirectable: Writable {
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _options: [Object],
          _ended: true,
          _ending: true,
          _redirectCount: 0,
          _redirects: [],
          _requestBodyLength: 81,
          _requestBodyBuffers: [],
          _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
          _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
          _currentUrl: 'myendpoint',
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
        [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
          accept: [Array],
          'content-type': [Array],
          'user-agent': [Array],
          'content-length': [Array],
          host: [Array]
        }
      },
      data: {
        access_token: 'ThisIsMyAccessKeyIGetBackAndWantToSave',
        expires_in: 3600,
        token_type: 'Bearer'
      }
    }
    2021-04-10T10:41:22.858Z    e5e3bc3a-f08d-4077-8897-709225abd5f8    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'data' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:26:48)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"]}
    END RequestId: e5e3bc3a-f08d-4077-8897-709225abd5f8
    REPORT RequestId: e5e3bc3a-f08d-4077-8897-709225abd5f8  Duration: 1631.22 ms    Billed Duration: 1632 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
    
    Request ID
    e5e3bc3a-f08d-4077-8897-709225abd5f8
```

What I am doing is sending client details to this endpoint and it returns a access key that is valid for a certain period. It does give a massive body back that is not needed and I only need to save the info in Data: but it keeps giving me the mentioned error even though I do get the correct response.

Comment: `postData.response.data` should be `postData.data`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks seems like all I had to do was define my key correctly

```
var mykey = postData.data.accesskey
```